# Why is Ellipse2D.Double not being recognized?

Tags: java, swing, awt, ellipse

Here is my code. I've used Ellipse2D.Double before so this is... weird.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D.Double;

public class Benzene extends JComponent
 {
     int size = 75; 
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        drawHex(size, g2);
        drawCircle(size, g2);
    }

public void drawHex(int size, Graphics2D g2){
    Polygon hexagon = new Polygon();
    Rectangle drawTest = new Rectangle(100,100,100,100);
    g2.draw(drawTest);
}

public void drawCircle(int size, Graphics2D g2){
    Ellipse2D.Double circle = new Ellipse2D.Double(100,100,size,size);
    g2.draw(circle);
}
```

}

How would I fix this error? Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer, but this happens a lot in Eclipse, see this type of question getting asked alot, you should see if you can find any similar answers (and quote them as not working if they didn't help you)

Answer (score 1):

You have to import `Ellipse2D` and not `Ellipse2D.Double`. Since Ellipse2D.Double is imported in your current code, Java expects you to reference it as just `Double` (which would cause confusion). It'll work perfectly if you simply change it to `import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;`